# How to use vue-cookies?

Tags: cookies, vuejs3

Sorry for the dummy question.

Where should I put this part:

```
$cookies.set(keyName, value[, expires[, path[, domain[, secure[, sameSite]]]]])
```

from this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cookies in my Vue3 web app?

I've already installed the package and added it to index.js like app.use(...), but I have no clue where to put the above-mentioned part from the description.

Comment: You can create a cookie anywhere.  When and where to use cookies depends on _why_ you want to use cookies.  What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: Since you're using Vue 3 you might want to use [this version instead](https://github.com/anish2690/vue-cookie-next#vue-cookie-next)

Comment: Me problem is, that if I try to insert this code snippet, it does simply not work.
Exectly which file should I put it to make it work? :)

Comment: It will work nearly anywhere, so if it doesn't work for you it's probably a problem with your specific usage which you've not shown.  "does not work" isn't a great description for a technical problem.  How do you know it doesn't work? What debugging have you done?  The documentation shows different instructions for use depending on your environment: vue 2 or vue 3.  options API or composition API.  If you have a problem, you'll need to show how you installed and how you're attempting to use.  Show the relevant code from `main.js` and wherever you're trying to use `$cookies.set`.